# how to list all image files in folder?

Tags: php

I want to have a list of only image files in a certain folder.
I tried this, but doesn't work for all files:

```
$files = scandir("/folder/");
foreach($files as $file) {
  if (substr($string, -4) == '.jpg'){
   $f[] = $file; 
 }
```

What would be the right way?

Comment: Have you read and tried some of the many tutorials available? Also, there are answers on here that can help with already existing PHP functionality... `glob()`...

Comment: thanks. i didn't know about glob()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get all the files, but leave out the ones starting with "."
Then a simple preg_match to get all image files

```
$files = array_diff( scandir("/folder/"), array(".", "..") ); 

$images = array()
for ($file in $file){
 if (preg_match("/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/", $file)){
   $images[] = $file;   
 }
}
```

or

```
$images = glob("/folder/*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);
```